# SQS is slow publishing requests

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-sqs

I have a Laravel application which sends data to SQS on nearly every request. However, every so often, one of these requests takes several seconds to execute. Attached is a stack trace from New Relic. It seems that the tick() method (within CURL) gets called many times and the seconds just pile up. It also seems to be making several attempts to connect to the same endpoint, though they are AWS services so I can't imagine they'd be unresponsive this often.

Any idea why this might occur?

My code is hosted on AWS, on two m4.large instances behind an ELB.  In general, the application is operating at a fairly low throughput -- roughly 50 - 100 requests per minute.

Stack trace: https://ibb.co/f05gLk

Additional thought: being that these instances are in a private subnet, is it possible the long request times to endpoints on SQS is a DNS-related issue?

Comment: Why dont you make a queue?

Comment: @sumit So make a local queue (redis?) to publish to my remote queue (Sqs)?  Does that imply that my bottleneck is on my server with the number of outgoing requests?

Comment: DNS is very hard to break in AWS if you are using their built-in resolver -- it has special handling in the infrastructure, is immune to security groups and Network ACLs, and doesn't need NAT to be working in order for DNS to resolve.  If you are using a NAT instance, try some `tshark` on the NAT instance to catch the request on the wire.  Definitely abnormal.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks Michael. I'm actually not using a NAT instance, but instead the NAT Gateway that AWS provides

Answer (score 0):

SQS pushes are slow(>50ms) sometimes (especially if your packet size is big). I noticed SQS pushes to take around 80ms for a fairly small packet(200k). I shifted the push to redis and a batched push from redis to sqs to solve this. 
I did not spend time investigating why the pushes are slow.

Comment: Interesting. My payloads to sqs are 200k across the board, however 90% connect quickly to sqs despite being that size. But 10% of them seem to randomly take a long time.  Is that still indicative of payload size? I would imagine if it were a payload size issue, they might all take a long time